# Selenium-IDE, how to "Please do not include core selenium in your add-on, instead just extend from the original one." for Mozilla Addons Signing

Tags: selenium

I have forked & extended the Selenium project from Github just to make small changes to a few Selenium IDE files. I dont know much of this project.

I use the go command for building it, but know nothing of it.

```
go.exe ide
```

When asked for review for Mozilla Addons Signing process, it got rejected with this suggestion.

> Please do not include core selenium in your add-on, instead just
>   extend from the original one.

Most probably they are asking to replace the libraries by the source-code of `selenium core`

**Selenium Core Libraries:**

[image: Selenium Core libraries]

**Selenium Core Source:**

[image]

Is this what Mozilla wants? If yes, how to do a build.

Comment: They probably want you to reference their library, and then extend their classes with your own custom classes using inheritance.  Instead of changing their library.

Comment: @MacGyver: Ahh, yes this makes sense. But i have to do that. Coz i have made overloads of some base methods, and tried to pass an extra object everywhere that those base methods have been passed.